# How to make Android Studio open (by default) by the batch file?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, java, android-studio

I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 21H1. When I try to open Android Studio from the Start menu, my cursor has a circle around it (as if something is loading) then nothing opens. If I navigate to the executable (both the 32-bit and 64-bit), it says that I don't have a compatible 32-bit JDK installed.

I couldn't find any 32-bit JDKs with version 11 or above as it asked, so I decided to set the environment variable it asked for to the bundled JDK., but it didn't work. I try running the `android.bat` file in the same directory, and it worked.

Is there a way to set Android Studio to automatically open using the .bat file?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shortcut to point at the batch file instead.

1. Right click the Android Studio icon.
2. Go to More-> Open file location.
3. Right click on the shortcut -> Properties.
4. Change start in: to your directory with the batch file.
5. Change target to the batch file path itself.  *A simple way to get the path is to hold down shift, right click, select "Copy as path".  You can also use this for step #4 and trim the file name off.*

This should work (I just did it on my machine).
*IF* it breaks your icon, use [Change Icon] and point it toward "<your_android_studio_path>Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" and you will get your icon back.

Before Microsoft broke the start menu (windows 8), this was much easier to do and manage.